# What is causing the 500 error on my Yoast SEO Sitemap?

Tags: wordpress, seo, sitemap, yoast, sitemap.xml

I am using Yoast SEO on one of my sites, and am having an issue where the Yoast sitemap doesn't load.

https://eatcleanmealprep.com/sitemap_index.xml

When you clear the cache, you get the following error: ***GET https://eatcleanmealprep.com/wp-content/plugins/wordpress-seo/css/main-sitemap.xsl net::ERR_ABORTED 500***

On Firefox the error appears as: ***Error loading stylesheet: Parsing an XSLT stylesheet failed.***

It appears that the page is failing to load the stylesheet that would populate the content, but I am having trouble figuring out what is causing this error. I've troubleshooted server issues and whitelisting the file, which didn't fix the issue.

Has anyone encountered this error before and have any idea what caused it, and what I might be able to look into to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Could be any of these:

1. Restart the server (Apache).
2. If you have a IIS (windows) web server, clear the pool.
3. If there is any cache server, flush the cache for that particular URL.
4. Remove the Yoast plugin, restart the server and install again.

Comment: Hello, thank you for this suggestion. We do not use IIS. Suggestions 1, 3 and 4 were tried, and did not fix the issue :/